# How to edit a http request header with axios?

Tags: javascript, jsp, http, axios

I want to add a string to a http post request header with using axios. This string is in the local storage of browser. Here is my related code:

index.jsp:

```
<script src="https://cdn.dwolla.com/1/dwolla.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form method="post" action="control">
Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" id="password pname=">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
<script>
    var token = localStorage.getItem("jwt").toString();
    // Here how can I add this token to request header with axios?
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

"control" is a java servlet. After I get the string from local storage, I do not know how to add this to header of post request. How can I do that?

Comment: That's plain HTML so whether this is a JSP shouldn't matter - an there's no relation to Java besides that. What you want is the JavaScript tag.

Comment: @Thomas Yes you are right, I edited now, thanks.